# how to use this in a callback-function?

Tags: angular, typescript, this

I use a third-Party-Component for which I have to create an Object for configuration like `itemMovementOptions` in the following sample code.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    readonly itemMovementOptions = {
      threshold: {
        horizontal: 25,
        vertical: 25,
      },
      events: {
        onMove({ items }) {
          for (let i = 0, len = items.after.length; i < len; i++) {
            const item = items.after[i];
            if (!this.canMove(item)) return items.before;
          }
          return items.after;
        },
      },
    };

    public canMove(item) {
       // ...
    }

    readonly config = {
        ItemResizing(this.itemResizeOptions),
        ItemMovement(this.itemMovementOptions),
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      GSTC.api.stateFromConfig(this.config);
    }
}
```

My Problem is now, that this is not pointing to AppComponent when the code will be executed so it could not find the method canMove().

Can someone help me, how I can solve this? I have to use canMove on several placed and do not want duplicate the code and putting it into the callback.

Comment: Can you shows us how do you use the itemMovementOptions please?

Comment: @manzapanza I have included this in the sample-code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

`this` binding is a source of confusion for new JS developers:

- For regular functions it comes from the call context.
- Arrow functions capture the `this` where the function is created rather than where it is invoked.

Observe:

```ts
class AppComponent  {
  onMoveFunction() {
    console.log("From onMoveFunction", this);
  }

  onMoveArrow = () => {
    console.log("From onMoveArrow", this);
  }
}

const c = new AppComponent();
const callbackFunction = c.onMoveFunction
const callbackArrow = c.onMoveArrow

c.onMoveFunction() // "From onMoveFunction",  AppComponent: {} 
c.onMoveArrow()    // "From onMoveArrow",  AppComponent: {} 
callbackFunction() // "From onMoveFunction",  undefined 
callbackArrow()    // "From onMoveArrow",  AppComponent: {}
```

Another option is to use `bind()`.

For more info:

- [this
  and arrow functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-and-arrow-functions)
- [You Don’t Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here depending on the content of your `canMove()` function:

1. If `canMove()` **does not** contain any references to `this` itself, that is, its logic is independent of the class/component that it is in, for example:

   `app.component.ts`

   ```
   canMove(item): boolean {
     return item.canMove;
   }
   ```

   then we can make the function static and reference it as follows:

   `app.component.ts`

   ```
   static canMove(item): boolean {
     return item.name;
   }

   ...
   if (!AppComponent.canMove(item)) return items.before;
   ...
   ```

   Note: This approach is also valid if the function is not in the component class, e.g.

   `utilities.ts`

   ```
   class Utilities {
     static canMove(item): boolean {
       return item.name;
     }
   }
   ```

   `app.component.ts`

   ```
   ...
   if (!Utilities.canMove(item)) return items.before;
   ...
   ```
2. If `canMove()` **does** contain references to `this`, i.e. its logic is dependent on some content in the class/component that it is in, for example:

   `app.component.ts`

   ```
   canMove(item): boolean {
     return item.canMove && this.canMoveOverride;
   }
   ```

   we then need to provide the originating class context to the function when it is referenced so that when it is executed, all of the `this.` variables it needs to access (which are all defined in `AppComponent`) will be available. This is achieved using `.bind()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind))

   `app.component.ts`

   ```
   ...
   if (!this.canMove(item).bind(this)) return items.before;
   ...
   ```

Comment: thank you for your help. canMove does reference to this, so I cannot make it static. When I try your approach with bind(this), I still get the exception ERROR TypeError: this.canMove is not a function